# Corona alpha transpency with display.newImage

Tags: lua, coronasdk, alpha

I want to display an image which has some alpha=50% transparency but my alpha is displayed as solid. 
I'm using display.newImage.
How do I use alphas? Many Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way. Alpha needs to be a fraction of 1.

```
local image = display.newImageRect( "bg.jpg", 100, 100 )
image.x = display.contentCenterX
image.y = display.contentCenterY
image.alpha = 0.5
```